# What is geometric autoregressive process?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

Can anyone give a definition for Geometric Autoregressive Process? Any specific properties? And, in what fields is this mostly applied?

To add some context to the question, here is a section of the original Mathematica code that mentions the process:

```
 n = 1000;
 \[Lambda] = n \[Gamma];
 \[CapitalDelta] = \[Sigma]/Sqrt[\[Lambda]];

 p = Table[(1 - z) Exp[t \[CapitalDelta]] + z, {t, -n, n}]; 

 (* (p - z)/(1 - z) follows a geometric AR (1); *)
```

Comment: A Google search identifies several candidates for the meaning, including [an AR process with geometric marginals](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1427183) and a [generalization of a renewal process](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~canccom/Publications/BraunPropGeoRelProc05.pdf). Could you provide a reference and a context for this term?

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks for your response. I encountered the term in a paper in economics. The author described a continuous state space approximation to the discrete state space model used in both the theory and simulation. The "Geometric Autoregressive Process" is mentioned in his code without explanation.

Comment: I added some further information in the question posted.

Comment: @HelloL I'm not familiar with mathematica code, but I may be able to offer help if the code is translated into mathematical equations. Any chance this could be done? Sometimes the formula for the sum of geometric series is used in ARIMA analysis in order to change the interpretation of the model, say, from MA($\infty$) to AR(1) or vice versa. Perhaps this is could be the meaning?

Comment: @Graeme It doesn't much matter, because this code does not define any kind of stochastic process, but here is what it does: $\Delta=\Sigma/\sqrt{n\Gamma}$; $p_t=(1-z)\exp(t\Delta)+z,t=-n,-n+1,\ldots,n$. (I guess $\Delta$, $\Sigma$, and $\Gamma$ are numbers.) It looks like a misunderstanding of a formula for an autoregressive process with multiplicative innovations.